# What is the longest additional time ever added in Europe's top five leagues?

Tags: football, trivia

What is the longest additional time ever used in Europe's top five leagues? Please mention the details of the match.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. **English Premier League**

A match between [Brentford and Wolverhampton](https://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/60005893) on 22 January 2022 had at least 19 minutes of stoppage time at the end of the first half, after the match had to be temporarily halted due to a drone hovering over the pitch.

> Referee Peter Bankes took both teams off the pitch just after the half-hour mark when the device was spotted above the Brentford Community Stadium.
>
> [...]
>
> When play did eventually resume, 19 minutes were added on at the end of the first half.

2. **La Liga**

[Barcelona vs Espanyol 2008](https://www.smh.com.au/sport/soccer/western-sydney-wanderers-and-guangzhou-play-longest-injury-time-in-asian-football-history-20150305-13vu1s.html) match got extended for 13 minutes.

> While not technically "injury time," the fireworks of the Catalan derby between Espanyol and Barcelona were extended for *13 minutes* in 2008 after fans continued to disrupt play.

3. **Ligue 1** (not sure whether this is longest or not)

[Strasbourg vs PSG 02 Dec 2017](http://www.bbc.com/sport/football/42208757) had nine minutes of stoppage time.

> PSG had chances to win during *nine minutes of stoppage time* ...

[Source](http://www.bbc.com/sport/football/42208757)

> Pressure was intensely applied to the Strasbourg goal, with nine minutes of stoppage time giving them even greater hope of a leveller.

[Source](http://www.espn.in/football/report?gameId=482262)

> Strasbourg defended relentlessly during *nine minutes of stoppage time* ...

[Source](https://www.foxsports.com.au/football/ligue-1/eurobeat-psgs-first-loss-of-season-to-ligue-1-minnow-bayern-munich-extend-bundesliga-lead/news-story/0a477e3b8f90647273b4c56f71568ffa)

4. **Bundesliga** (not sure whether this is longest or not)

[Cologne vs Hamburg 2017](http://www.goal.com/en-tza/news/lewis-holtby-makes-history-with-100th-minute-goal-in-bizarre/ftj7bndw6bj1sbv3edfpcu0e) had 13 minutes of added time. In this game Lewis Hotlby made history by scoring a Bundesliga goal in the 100th minute.

> A bizarre Bundesliga match between Cologne and Hamburg saw two goals and a VAR review during over *13 minutes of added time*

[Source](http://www.goal.com/en-tza/news/lewis-holtby-makes-history-with-100th-minute-goal-in-bizarre/ftj7bndw6bj1sbv3edfpcu0e)

> The extremely late action came because of an injury to referee Felix Brych early in the second half, with the final whistle ultimately blown in the *114th minute*.

[Source](http://sports.opera.com/?sport=soccer&page=news&view=article&news_id=1028489&localization_id=www)

---

Other notable matches:

- [Brentford vs Bristol City in 2000-01](https://www.theguardian.com/football/2006/nov/29/theknowledge.sport) [2](http://news.bbc.co.uk/sport2/hi/football/890491.stm)

> ...there were about **23 minutes of stoppage time in the first-half alone** after a broken leg, a dislocated shoulder (Bees striker Lloyd Owusu passed out from the pain and an ambulance had to be driven up to the pitch), and serious concussion caused the delay...

- [Western Sydney Wanderers vs Guangzhou Evergrande](https://www.smh.com.au/sport/soccer/western-sydney-wanderers-and-guangzhou-play-longest-injury-time-in-asian-football-history-20150305-13vu1s.html)

> **Seventeen minutes** did the board read, the longest added time in the Asian Champions league, the A-League and all recorded Asian premier leagues.

- [Mexico vs Panama Gold Cup](https://www.foxsports.com/soccer/gold-cup/story/mexico-advance-gold-cup-final-controversial-calls-panama-2-1-andres-guardado-match-report-072215)

> Geiger then awarded an 89th-minute penalty when Torres fell on the ball after an attempted clearance to plunge the game into extra time and spark a *10-minute stoppage* marred by flying beverages and scuffles on the field.

[Source](https://www.foxsports.com/soccer/gold-cup/story/mexico-advance-gold-cup-final-controversial-calls-panama-2-1-andres-guardado-match-report-072215)

> The match was *delayed for more than 10 minutes* before order was restored.

[Source](http://www.businessinsider.com/gold-cup-panama-mexico-penalty-2015-7)

---

<sub>Note: Haven't found any resources for Serie A, not sure the one I mentioned for Ligue 1, Bundesliga is the longest or not. Question mentions injury/stoppage time. Thanks to [dly](https://sports.stackexchange.com/users/14543/dly) for information on Bundesliga.</sub>

Comment: It's not worth an answer of its own, but in the Bundesliga it was (probably) HSV - Cologne with [14 minutes](http://www.goal.com/en-tza/news/lewis-holtby-makes-history-with-100th-minute-goal-in-bizarre/ftj7bndw6bj1sbv3edfpcu0e) when the ref got injured and had to be replaced.

Comment: I'd like to suggest an addition to the "other notable matches" section: [an FA Cup first-round tie](https://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/live/football/54751462) between Torquay United and Crawley Town that featured at least 21 minutes of second-half stoppage time.